# How to assign articles to specific users based on criteria?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In drupal-8, I have logged users. Those users are grouped by different interests (right now it is not implemented, just at analysis level). For example:

- User1: java, php, .net
- User2: infrastructure, java
- User3: java, php, bpm

I want to achieve (is it possible?) that if the content manager publishes an article referring to the "php" interest, the only users logged that should see that article published on the first page after they logged, should be User1 and User3 as they have interest in "php".

I've found that I can create drupal roles which I assume those should be "interests" in my case. 
Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that and it is [group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)